# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method dist(FFFF)F in class Landroid/util/MathUtils

Tags: android

After the SDK was upgraded to 28, there was a problem with the sliding screen

logs

W/com.xxx.xxxx: Accessing hidden method Landroid/util/MathUtils;->dist(FFFF)F (dark greylist, linking) 
E/ContentCatcher: Interceptor : dispatchTouchEvent-Error: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method dist(FFFF)F in class Landroid/util/MathUtils; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.util.MathUtils' appears in /system/framework/framework.jar!classes2.dex)

Comment: I have the same problem here and have no clue. :(

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same problem with you. My test phone is MI MIX 2s with android 9.0. But I cant find this error on Pixel with android 9.0 .

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same problem with you. My test phone is MI MIX 2s with android 9.0. But I cant find this error on Pixel with android 9.0 .

You can try set android:debuggable="false" in your AndroidManifest.xml->application

Comment: Your solution will in no way help.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem in my case. When I had:

```
android:targetSdkVersion="27"
```

In **AndroidManifest.xml** I could access hidden API without a problem, however after changing to:

```
android:targetSdkVersion="28"
```

it was no longer possible. Code was built fine, app also started fine and I could see such log when app started:

```
Accessing hidden method Landroid/bluetooth/BluetoothHeadsetClient;->startVoiceRecognition(Landroid/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice;)Z (dark greylist, linking)
```

However when I triggered this method by button click app crashed with:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method startVoiceRecognition(Landroid/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice;)Z in class Landroid/bluetooth/BluetoothHeadsetClient; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.bluetooth.BluetoothHeadsetClient' appears in /system/framework/framework.jar)
```

This behavior is actually documented [here](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/restrictions-non-sdk-interfaces) and is a design decision made by Google. There are some ways like **whitelisting** your app or signing it with **platform key** which will allow you to use hidden API. You can read about them in link I've shared.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug of MIUI, confirmed by my former workmate in Xiaomi

BTW, it was found when I investigated the topic in
https://developer-support.myscript.com/support/discussions/topics/16000024921

Comment: don't just put the link. add more details